# Adjectives separated by comma vs a chain

Tags: adjective

I kept searching on internet of this topic but I can't find any good results, and I feel sort of uneasy giving examples. So could someone guide me on how to do the task in the question?

WHen I say "multiple adjectives" I don't mean adjectives separated by a comma, or chained up through connectors like "und" or "aber", but rather simply one adjective written after another before a noun.

How do the meaning of multipile adjectives differ from adjectives seperated by a comma?

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. What's unclear about this question?

Answer (score 6):

That's very tricky and I guess, most of native German speakers can't tell for sure when to put a comma between adjectives and when not to do so.

The [rule](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Komma-zwischen-Adjektiven) is:

- put a comma between equal-ranking adjectives with enumerating character
- don't put a comma between to adjectives, if the second one belongs to a fixed term together with the noun

All clear? No. Of course not. As a rule of thumb: if you could easily use *und* between the adjectives, put a comma. Otherwise don't.

In real life it's much more complicated. What is a fixed term?

Duden gives the example *wolkenloser blauer Himmel*. So we are talking about the *blue sky* and add the attribute *cloudless*. It would sound a little bit strange to say *cloudless **and** blue sky*, wouldn't it?

On the other hand:

> das große alte rote Feuerwehrauto

Are the adjectives of enumerating character? Well a firetruck is red most of the time so one could say *red firetruck* is a fixed term. And then what about *big* and *old*? Isn't that equal-ranking, enumerating? So would it have to be

> das große, alte rote Feuerwehrauto?

Now don't even ask about of a switching meaning between the same phrase with or without comma!

[Leo](https://blog.leo.org/2018/04/12/die-bekannte-leidige-frage-nach-dem-komma-zwischen-adjektiven/) gives some more or less convincing hints. And it gives another rule of thumb:

If you have to put a clear pause between two adjectives in a spoken sentence to transport the right meaning, then put a comma.

You see: that's not a very well suited subject for learners at the beginning of their journey. So my advice for them would be: if in doubt, put a comma!

Comment: So, mostly three adjectives in a row without comma are almost nonexistent (if I correctly understood), since fixed terms with two adjectives are.

Comment: @c.p. I wouldn't swear but I think: yes!

Answer (score 0):

So you mean adjective rows before a noun? You can translate them to English quite literally as the order of adjectives is the same in German and English.

> das große alte rote Feuerwehrauto — the big old red fire engine

Comment: How would meaning differ if they were seperated by comma

Comment: Commas are used for lists. But that's also true for plain adjectives — they are already a list. So if you use commas with an adjective list, you emphasize that those adjectives are not in the usual hierarchy. For example: *das alte, große rote Feuerwehrauto* should be written with a comma for the out-of-order element. That shows the reader that it's the old one we are talking about. Not the new one.